# Integrate the nsis installer with electron application. But, Desktop application window not open

Tags: electron, nsis, silent-installer

I'm creating electron desktop application.

So, I have a idea with integrate the nsis installer and electron desktop application.

Actually, I'm creating electron application exe and Installer exe. Then, I'm integrate using null script. Integrated exe is created. Installation relay window's also came after installation done. Application also came in the system desktop. While click the application, Application window not open this is the problem

Actual : I'm creating electron application exe and NSIS Installer exe. Then, I'm integrate using null script. Integrated exe is created. Installation relay window's also came after installation done. Application also came in the system desktop. While click the application, Application window not open this is the problem

Expect : After installation is done. While click the application, Application window should.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.